# Get height and width from a phaser canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, phaser-framework

So I use [phaser.io](http://phaser.io) but I want to print an array so I create it in my page html.

To put the height and width of my array I need to know the height and width of my canvas.

So I just should just do :

```
$('canvas').height();
```

Mission complete.

But not there is a trap my canvas look like this :

```
<canvas width="1261" height="1101" style="display: block; touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); width: 1059px; height: 925px; cursor: inherit; margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px;"></canvas>
```

And each time it return me the value from height not the one from the style.

So I try other way :

```
$('canvas').css('height');
$('canvas').[0].style.height;
$('canvas')[0].style.cssText;
```

But I always get the wrong result

what is super weird is that when I do :

```
console.log($('canvas')[0].style)
```

I see exactly the result I want inside the element 'height' and 'cssText'. I put a part of the result here :

```
 0:"display"
    1:"touch-action"
    2:"user-select"
    3:"-webkit-tap-highlight-color"
    4:"width"
    5:"height"
    6:"margin-left"
    7:"margin-right"
    8:"margin-top"
    ...
    cssText:"display: block; touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); width: 1059px; height: 925px; margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px;"
    ...
    height:"925px"
    ...
```

Someone can tell me why? and give me a solution can be nice also.

======= EDIT =======

I get some news when I do $('canvas').height() on a click on an element it's work. Actualy I can deal with it but I still don't understand why when I do :

```
console.log($('canvas')[0].style.cssText);
console.log($('canvas').height());
```

Just the one after the other I get different result. Certainly a question of loading time ... but still don't sound good to me.

```js
window.onload = function() {
 
 var Level = {
  preload: function()
  {
   console.log("toto");
  },
        create: function()
  {
   console.log($('canvas').height());
   console.log($('canvas')[0].style.cssText);
   
   this.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
      this.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
      this.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
            this.scale.refresh();
  }
    }
 const SAFE_ZONE_WIDTH=640;
 const SAFE_ZONE_HEIGHT=1101;

 var w = window.innerWidth ;
 var h = window.innerHeight ;
 var aspectRatioDevice = w/h;

 var aspectRatioSafeZone = SAFE_ZONE_WIDTH / SAFE_ZONE_HEIGHT;
 var extraWidth = 0, extraHeight = 0, offsetWidth = 0;
 if (aspectRatioSafeZone < aspectRatioDevice) 
 {
  // have to add game pixels horizontally in order to fill the device screen
  extraWidth = aspectRatioDevice * SAFE_ZONE_HEIGHT - SAFE_ZONE_WIDTH;
  offsetWidth = extraWidth/2;
 } 
 else 
 {
  // have to add game pixels vertically
  extraHeight = SAFE_ZONE_WIDTH / aspectRatioDevice - SAFE_ZONE_HEIGHT;
 }

 var game = new Phaser.Game( SAFE_ZONE_WIDTH + extraWidth, SAFE_ZONE_HEIGHT + extraHeight, Phaser.CANVAS, 'game_div');

 game.state.add('Level', Level);
 game.state.start('Level');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, height = device-height, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi = device-dpi" />
<title>niuniu</title>
<script>
    screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
</script>
<script src="https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser-ce/releases/download/v2.9.4/phaser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Phaser (v3) you have access to `game.canvas`, which is the canvas (element) Phaser is running on, so:

```js
const game = new Phaser.Game({ ... });
console.log(game.canvas.width, game.canvas.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of

`$('canvas').height()` or

`$('canvas').attr('height')` or

`$('canvas').css('height')`

```js
console.log($('canvas').height());
console.log($('canvas').css('height'));
console.log($('canvas').attr('height'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="1261" height="1101" style="display: block; touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); width: 1059px; height: 925px; cursor: inherit; margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Same result for both i get 1101

Comment: @Kvasir Did you clicked on _Run code snippet_ above button. See console

Comment: @Kvasir Try `$('canvas').css('height')`. Updated above.

Comment: @Kvasir what result you are getting from `$('canvas').css('height')`?

Comment: I still get 1101

Comment: How it possible? the `css()` function get the value from style tag. May be in your style tag height is coming 1101.

Comment: Is it my question how is it possible.

Comment: I try but i don't get the same result at all

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize Phaser, it usually looks something like this:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, Phaser.AUTO, 'game');
```

or something similar. You take whatever variable you set equal to the Phaser.Game (in my case it is `game`. To get the width, all you need to do is

```
var width = game.width;
var height = game.height;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey ça fait très longtemps que j'ai posé cette question et je n'ai actuelement plus phaser d'installer sur ma machine donc ça va être compliqué de retester surtout que des fois ça fonctionnais des fois non.
Si quelqu'un confirme que celà résout le problème je validerais. Mais je ne pense pas.

Comment: Le test est facile: vous pouvez taper "game.width" dans la console sur une page avec phaser. Je m'excuse si mon français est terrible.

Comment: Sorry for that I didn't even see that I write in french. Kind of append when I don't pay attention. Here is the translate : 
It's been a long time since I asked this question and I currently don't have phaser anymore on my machine so it will be difficult to test your answer especially because sometimes it worked sometimes not. 
If someone confirms that this solves the problem I will validate. But I do not think so. If I remember well I tried this before and get the same weird result.